# How can I prevent query strings from impacting Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, query-string

In Google Analytics I am seeing URLs that should be treated as the same page are showing in GA as unique.

For example:

```
/?optimizely_log=false&optimizely_cache_buster=1389806928991
/?optimizely_log=false&optimizely_cache_buster=1389806937020
```

Should be treated as the same page for analytic purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLs that differ even by one character are still considered to be unique.

Fortunately, Google Analytics provides an option to **Exclude URL Query Parameters**, as covered [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en):

1.) Click **Admin** at the top of any Analytics page.

2.) Use the menu in the *View* column to select the view you want to edit.

3.) Click **View Settings**.

4.) Under *Exclude URL Query Parameters*:  Enter any query parameters that appear in your URLs that you do not want to see in your reports as a comma-separated list (this setting is case sensitive, and there's a 255-character limit).

That should then look like this to exclude the parameters in your URLs:

[image]